How to use SMTP in ASP.NET Core
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core project and get an error when using SMTP.
This is my current code:
string code = GenerateRandom6DigitString();
string subject = "Your Verification Code";

string body = $"Welcome to website!!!\n\nYour verification code is: **{code}**.\n\nPlease enter this code to verify your account.\n\nThank you!";

string myEmail = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EMAIL_ADDRESS") ?? string.Empty;
string myEmailPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EMAIL_PASSWORD") ?? string.Empty;
string mySmtpHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SMTP_HOST") ?? string.Empty;

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(myEmail);
mail.To.Add(email);
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(mySmtpHost, 587)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myEmail, myEmailPassword),
            EnableSsl = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        };

try
{
    smtpClient.Send(mail);

    lock (lockVerifyValueDict)
    {
        verifyValueDict.Add(email, code);
    }

    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to send email. Email: {email} Error: {ex.Message}");
    return false;
}

And env file is as following:
EMAIL_ADDRESS=myname@gmail.com
EMAIL_PASSWORD=password
SMTP_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

But I can't send any mail using this code.
In my opinion, it's because of google security settings.
If anybody know about google security settings for smtp, please help me.
Thank you.

"... and met an error in using smtp" What error? May be include the stack trace too.

What error does Google give you?

NB: SmtpClient class: "We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use MailKit or other libraries instead. For more information, see SmtpClient shouldn't be used on GitHub."

You doesn't have to enable anything specific in GMail. In case you're using 2FA you must create an app password which you can do here. I tested it on my own account with MailKit using the following code:
using MimeMessage message = new();
message.From.Add(InternetAddress.Parse("myAddress@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(InternetAddress.Parse("targetAddress@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "Message send from C#";

using SmtpClient client = new();
await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
await client.AuthenticateAsync("myAddress@gmail.com", "The pwd or app pwd");
await client.SendAsync(message);


Thank you for your response, but unfortunately, it's not solution.
I tested connection using telnet, but the it was not connected.
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
If you know how to use proxy in mailkit, please let me know.
Thank you.

I dont relay know why you want to use a proxy or what telnet has to do with this but to answer you question yes you can use a proxy which shown here.

Thank you.
I solved problem perfectly with your response.
I just used app password.
